# pandas read_sql_table() throws "Table not found" error

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

There is a lot of info out there for SQLAlchemy connection string configuration, but I am not able to successfully connect to a SQL Server 2019 instance using Windows Authentication.  What might be wrong with this approach?  I am receiving "Table not Found" error (it does exist).

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=myservername;DATABASE=mydbname;Trusted_Connection=yes"

connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(connection_url)

tablename = "mytablename"

df = pd.read_sql_table(tablename, con=engine)
```

Comment: Set `sql = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytablename'"` and then do `df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)`. Does the DataFrame contain a row for your table? If so, what is the `TABLE_SCHEMA` value?

Comment: It does return a row with table name, for schema dbo.  pd.read_sql_table returns InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine. - which happens using dbo.tablename, and also just tablename, either way.

Comment: Okay, then try `df = pd.read_sql_table("mytablename", engine, schema="dbo")`